# Unable to find user with upn with email address: user@domain.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, command-line-interface

I typed this cmd to grant permission for keyvault to access storage account with upn of my address (as the only user of the subscription) in order to manage storage access keys:

```
az keyvault set-policy -n keyvault02 --upn user@domain.com --storage-permissions get list delete set update regeneratekey getsas listsas deletesas setsas recover backup restore purge
```

but I faced this error message :

```
Unable to find user with upn 'user@domain.com'
Unable to get object id from principal name
```

Is there an issue with AD licence (requiring a particular licence) or something else?

Waiting for your help

---

**If the question helped, up-vote it. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: To look up a list of the current users and their upn value, run `az ad user list`. My upn was different than my Azure portal login email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue:
[image]

---

The User Principal Name in the portal maybe not the command used. This is my workaround:

```
# get user principal name(upn)
az ad user show --id {user-object-id}
```

[image]

```
# Give your user account permission to managed storage accounts    
az keyvault set-policy --name {the key vault name} --upn {the user principal name} --storage-permissions get list delete set update regeneratekey getsas listsas deletesas setsas recover backup restore purge
```

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hello Pamela

Thanls for help, it works !  

The reason is that I passed an invalid string as UPN (I used my original address email), It should be the one with : .............#EXT#@..................onmicrosoft.com

Regards,

Comment: It's my pleasure.:)